# CellValueFactory of a TableColumn using a generic Object type?

Tags: java, generics, javafx, tableview, treetableview

Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from `SimpleStringProperty` to `ObservableValue<Object>`.

I am trying to create a TreeTableView with a column that manages various data types. This means that each row could use one of three or so types of data ( `String`, `int`, `StringProperty`, or `ObjectProperty< LocalDate >`.

Given my data-type is "Object" then `setCellValueFactory( cellDataFeatures -> { return ...; })` expects an `ObservableValue< Object >`. I am at a loss trying to get the required ObservableValue out of the Properties for the CellValueFactory callback. :(

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334450/cannot-convert-from-string-to-observablevaluestring) suggests using a `ReadOnlyStringWrapper` but I would like to keep to the value editable (in most cases). I've also found suggestions for the `#asObject()` method which is not available in a StringProperty.

```
        /*-------------------------+------------+ 
         | columnPeople            | columnData |
         +-------------------------+------------+ 
         |                         |            |
         | + Bob Rozz ============ | 33 ======= |
         |   + SKILLS              |            |
         |     + testskill 1       | 0.7        |
         |                         | 3/14/2017  |
         |     + testskill 2       |            |
         |                         | 0.9        |
         |                         | 3/11/2017  |
         |                         |            |
         | + Bob Dilly =========== | 34 ======= |
         |   + SKILLS              |            |
         |     + testskill 1       | 0.6        |
         |                         | 3/10/2017  |
         |     + testskill 2       |            |
         |                         | 0.5        |
         |                         | 3/17/2017  |
         +-------------------------+------------+ 
        */
```

**Note1**: Not tackling the `setCellFactory(...)` yet.

**Note2**: As-presented, I realize this example is unpractical. It is completely separate from my project as an example of the desired functionality.

```
package testGenericTableTreeColumn;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleFloatProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Pair;
import javafx.util.converter.DefaultStringConverter;



public class testGenericTableTreeColumn extends javafx.application.Application {

    class Skill {

        private StringProperty        name = new SimpleStringProperty( "" );
        public  final String          getName(){ return this.name.get();         }
        public  final void            setName( String v ){ name.set(v); return;  }
        public  StringProperty        nameProperty(){ return this.name;          }

        private SimpleFloatProperty   value = new SimpleFloatProperty( 0f );
        public  final String          getValue(){ return this.name.get();        }
        public  final void            setValue( String v ){ name.set(v); return; }
        public  StringProperty        valueProperty(){ return this.name;         }

        private SimpleObjectProperty< LocalDate > date = new SimpleObjectProperty< LocalDate >( LocalDate.now() );//LocalDate date  = LocalDate.now();
        public  final String          getDate(){ return this.name.get();         }
        public  final void            setDate( String v ){ name.set(v); return;  }
        public  StringProperty        dateProperty(){ return this.name;          }

        public Skill( String name ){
            java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
            this.name  .set( name );                        //this.name  = name;
            this.value .set( 100 * ( r.nextFloat() ));      //this.value = 100 * ( r.nextFloat() );
            this.date  .get().minusWeeks( r.nextInt(10) );  //date.minusWeeks( r.nextInt(10) );
            return;
        }
    }
    class Person {

        private StringProperty  name = new SimpleStringProperty( "" );
        public final String     getName()          { return this.name.get(); }
        public final void       setName( String v ){ name.set(v); return;    }
        public StringProperty   nameProperty()     { return this.name;       }

        private IntegerProperty age = new SimpleIntegerProperty( 0 );
        public final int        getAge()           { return this.age.get();  }
        public final void       setAge( int v )    { age.set(v); return;     }
        public IntegerProperty  ageProperty()      { return this.age;        }

        public  List< Skill >   skills = new ArrayList<>();

        public Person( String name, int age ){
            this.name .set( name );
            this.age  .set( age  );
            skills.add( new Skill( "testskill 1" ));
            skills.add( new Skill( "testskill 2" ));
            return;
        }
    }

    public TreeTableView< Pair< Object, Object >> table = new TreeTableView<>();

    @Override public void start( Stage primaryStage ){

        TreeItem< Pair< Object, Object >> itemRoot = new TreeItem<>( new Pair<>( "PEOPLE", null ));
        this.table.setRoot( itemRoot );

        Person person1 = new Person( "Bob Rozz"  ,33 );
        Person person2 = new Person( "Bob Dilly" ,34 );

        List< Person > people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add( person1 );
        people.add( person2 );

        /*-------------------------+------------+ 
         | columnPeople            | columnData |
         +-------------------------+------------+ 
         |                         |            |
         | + Bob Rozz ============ | 33 ======= |
         |   + SKILLS              |            |
         |     + testskill 1       | 0.7        |
         |                         | 3/14/2017  |
         |     + testskill 2       |            |
         |                         | 0.9        |
         |                         | 3/11/2017  |
         |                         |            |
         | + Bob Dilly =========== | 34 ======= |
         |   + SKILLS              |            |
         |     + testskill 1       | 0.6        |
         |                         | 3/10/2017  |
         |     + testskill 2       |            |
         |                         | 0.5        |
         |                         | 3/17/2017  |
         +-------------------------+------------+ 
        */

        for ( Person person : people ){

            TreeItem< Pair< Object, Object >> treeItemPerson = new TreeItem<>( new Pair< Object, Object >( person.nameProperty(), person.ageProperty() ));
            TreeItem< Pair< Object, Object >> treeItemSkills = new TreeItem<>( new Pair< Object, Object >( "Skills"             , null ));

            itemRoot       .getChildren().add( treeItemPerson );
            treeItemPerson .getChildren().add( treeItemSkills );

            for ( Skill skill : person.skills ){

                TreeItem< Pair< Object, Object >> treeItemSkillName  = new TreeItem<>( new Pair< Object, Object >( null, skill.nameProperty  () ));
                TreeItem< Pair< Object, Object >> treeItemSkillValue = new TreeItem<>( new Pair< Object, Object >( null, skill.valueProperty () ));
                TreeItem< Pair< Object, Object >> treeItemSkillDate  = new TreeItem<>( new Pair< Object, Object >( null, skill.dateProperty  () ));

                treeItemSkills    .getChildren().add( treeItemSkillName  );
                treeItemSkillName .getChildren().add( treeItemSkillDate  );
                treeItemSkillName .getChildren().add( treeItemSkillValue );
            }
        }

        TreeTableColumn< Pair< Object, Object>, String > colName = new TreeTableColumn<>("People"); colName.setMinWidth(100);
        colName.setCellValueFactory( cellDataFeatures -> {

            // Could be a String, StringProperty, or ObjectProperty< LocalDate >
            Object item   = cellDataFeatures.getValue().getValue().getKey();

            //String
            if ( item instanceof String ){
                /* ERROR */ return ( String ) item; //ERROR: Type mismatch: cannot convert from SimpleStringProperty to ObservableValue< Object >
            }

            //StringProperty
            if ( item instanceof StringProperty ){
                /* ERROR */ return (( StringProperty ) item ); //ERROR: Type mismatch: cannot convert from SimpleStringProperty to ObservableValue< Object >
            }
        });

        TreeTableColumn< Pair< Object, Object>, Object > colData = new TreeTableColumn<>("Skills"); colData.setMinWidth(200);
        colData.setCellValueFactory( cellDataFeatures -> {

            //itemKey : Could be a String, IntegerProperty, StringProperty, or ObjectProperty< LocalDate >
            Object item = cellDataFeatures.getValue().getValue().getValue();

            //String
            if ( item instanceof String ){
                /* ERROR */ return (String) item; //ERROR: Type mismatch: cannot convert from SimpleStringProperty to ObservableValue< Object >
            }

            //IntegerProperty
            if ( item instanceof IntegerProperty ){
                /* ERROR */ return (( IntegerProperty ) item ); //ERROR: Type mismatch: cannot convert from SimpleIntegerProperty to ObservableValue< Object >
            }

            //StringProperty
            if ( item instanceof StringProperty ){
                /* ERROR */ return (( StringProperty ) item ); //ERROR: Type mismatch: cannot convert from SimpleStringProperty to ObservableValue< Object >
            }

            //ObjectProperty< LocalDate >
            if ( item instanceof ObjectProperty< ? >){
                Object value = (( ObjectProperty<?> ) item ).getBean();
                if ( value instanceof LocalDate ){
                    //@TODO LocalDate cell
                }
            }
        });

        /*
        //colData.setCellFactory( new Callback< TreeTableColumn< Person, Object >, TreeTableCell< Person, Object >>());
        colData.setCellFactory( column -> {

            TreeTableCell< Object, Object > cell = new TreeTableCell< Object, Object >(){
                @Override protected void updateItem( Object newValue, boolean empty ){

                    this.setEditable( false );

                    super.updateItem( newValue, empty );
                    if ( empty || newValue == null ){
                        setText    ( null );
                        setGraphic ( null );
                        return;
                    }

                    if ( newValue instanceof String ){
                        return;
                    }

                    this.setEditable( true );

                    if ( newValue instanceof LocalDate ){
                        return;
                    }

                    return;
                }   // updateItem( ... );
            };
        });
        // */

        // Type safety: A generic array of Table... is created for a varargs
        // parameter
        // -> @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") to start method!
        table.getColumns().addAll( colName, colData );

        // Output in console the selected table view's cell value/class to check
        // that the data type is correct.
        //  SystemOutTreeTableViewSelectedCell.set(tableView);
        /*
        // To check that table view is correctly refreshed on data changed..
        final Button agePlusOneButton = new Button("Age +1");
        agePlusOneButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            Person<?> person = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            try {
                person.setAge(person.getAge() + 1);
            } catch (NullPointerException npe ){
                //
            }
        });
        */

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll( table );

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        primaryStage.setWidth(600);
        primaryStage.setHeight(750);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Type mismatch: cannot convert from IntegerProperty to ObservableValue<Object>   testGenericTableTreeColumn.java /testGenericTableTreeColumn/src/testGenericTableTreeColumn  line 300    Java Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to ObservableValue<Object>    testGenericTableTreeColumn.java /testGenericTableTreeColumn/src/testGenericTableTreeColumn  line 295    Java Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to ObservableValue<String>    testGenericTableTreeColumn.java /testGenericTableTreeColumn/src/testGenericTableTreeColumn  line 278    Java Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from StringProperty to ObservableValue<Object>    testGenericTableTreeColumn.java /testGenericTableTreeColumn/src/testGenericTableTreeColumn  line 305    Java Problem
```

Java Version:

```
java version "1.8.0_121" Java(TM)
SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Some of these don't generate the compile errors you claim they do, e.g. in `colName` the only error can be fixed by casting `item` to a `String` in the first `if` clause. (The second cast should really be to `StringProperty`, not `SimpleStringProperty`, but it will compile as it stands.) In `colData` you can just return a `new SimpleObjectProperty<>(...)` and pass in the appropriate value: `item.getValue()` if `item` is some kind of property, or just `item` otherwise.

Comment: Well it wont compile for me. It cant even find the main class because it has errors. java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: I tried to make the changes you suggested and updated my first post to reflect that. I also posted the errors I'm getting at the end. Thanks.

Comment: Well, under the same JDK, I don't get those same compile errors. However, the fundamental errors you need to fix are that the lambda expressions in your `cellValueFactory`s must return a value under every possible code path. For example, in the factory for `colName`, if `item` is neither a `String` nor a `StringProperty`, you never reach a `return` statement. Furthermore, you need to return the correct type (an `ObservableValue<String>` in the `colName` factory): you cannot return a `String` as you do in the first `if`: do `return new SimpleStringProperty((String)item);`.

Comment: Probably since the code structure is broken (i.e. you don't reach `return` statements in every code path), the compiler is confused enough that it can't generate the correct error messages in the other cases.

Comment: Wait: When I cast the returns of `colName.setCellFactory(...)` to StringProperty, it is fine. However this doesnt work for `colData.setCellFactory(...)`. Hmmmmm. Looking into this further....

Comment: No, I'm not on windows. It's not a bug anywhere. Your code is not valid, and you're getting compile errors: that is normal, expected, and correct behavior. Different compilers (e.g. using different IDEs) will report errors differently (particularly when there are multiple confounding errors, as in this case). That said, I simply do not believe you in some of the claims. E.g. for the first return statement in the factory for `colName` I get "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to ObservableValue<String>" in my version of eclipse, not the error you claim it gives.

Comment: Well, of course it doesn't work for `colData`: `colData` has a different type. Have you read my answer?

Comment: Yes, I'm not very good at generics. I got that. My original view was that these are all of type "Object" so thats finally out the window. -- Trying to follow your suggestions : So now, only in `colData.setCellValueFactory(...)` am I'm needing to return a type `Object`. You suggested I use `SimpleObjectProperty<>` and I see that does indeed work.

Comment: "I am still confused as to where it gets the type from". The compiler just looks at the compile-time type of the value you are returning. The compile-time type of `(String) item` is `String` (basically by definition of what a downcast is). The compile-time type of `(StringProperty) item` is `StringProperty`. Note that `StringProperty` is a subtype of `ObservableValue<String>`, but not of `ObservableValue<Object>`.

Comment: Ha-ha! Thanks again.  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `TreeTableColumn<S,T>`, the `cellValueFactory` has type `Callback<CellDataFeatures<S,T>, ObservableValue<S,T>>`, which is essentially a function taking an instance of `CellDataFeatures<S,T>` and returning an `ObservableValue<S,T>`.

Your `colName` is a `TreeTableColumn<Pair<Object, Object>, String>`, so `S` is `Pair<Object, Object>` and `T` is `String`. So the `cellValueFactory` for `colName` is a function taking a `CellDataFeatures<Pair<Object, Object>>` instance (which you call `cellDataFeatures`) and returning an `ObservableValue<String>`.

There are multiple problems with your implementation. The first is that if `item`, which is declared as an `Object`, is not an instance of either `String` or `StringProperty`, then the code never actually reaches a `return` statement. So this isn't even a valid lambda expression.

The second problem is that if `item` is a `String` instance (first `if` statement), you return a `String`, which is not an `ObservableValue<String>`, so you are returning the wrong type.

So an implementation that will at least compile is

```
    TreeTableColumn< Pair< Object, Object>, String > colName = new TreeTableColumn<>("People"); colName.setMinWidth(100);
    colName.setCellValueFactory( cellDataFeatures -> {

        // Could be a String, StringProperty, or ObjectProperty< LocalDate >
        Object item   = cellDataFeatures.getValue().getValue().getKey();

        //String
        if ( item instanceof String ){
            return new SimpleStringProperty(( String ) item); 
        }

        //StringProperty
        if ( item instanceof StringProperty ){
            return (( StringProperty ) item ); 
        }

        // must return something: you probably don't want to return null though, so you should fix this as needed.
        return null ;
    });
```

Similarly, for `colData`, you have code paths that never reach a return statement, so you have not defined a valid lambda expression. In this case, `colData` is a `TreeTableColumn<Pair<Object, Object>, Object>`, so `T` is `Object`, and the return type must be `ObservableValue<Object>`. Your various `if` blocks attempt to return `String`, `IntegerProperty`, `StringProperty`, (or something to be determined), and none of those are instances of `ObservableValue<Object>`.

An implementation that actually compiles is

```
    TreeTableColumn< Pair< Object, Object>, Object > colData = new TreeTableColumn<>("Skills"); colData.setMinWidth(200);
    colData.setCellValueFactory( cellDataFeatures -> {

        //itemKey : Could be a String, IntegerProperty, StringProperty, or ObjectProperty< LocalDate >
        Object item = cellDataFeatures.getValue().getValue().getValue();

        //String
        if ( item instanceof String ){
            return new SimpleObjectProperty<>( item ); 
        }

        //IntegerProperty
        if ( item instanceof IntegerProperty ){
            return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(((IntegerProperty) item).getValue()); 
        }

        //StringProperty
        if ( item instanceof StringProperty ){
            return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(((IntegerProperty) item).getValue()); 
        }

        //ObjectProperty< LocalDate >
        if ( item instanceof ObjectProperty< ? >){
            Object value = (( ObjectProperty<?> ) item ).getBean();
            if ( value instanceof LocalDate ){
                //@TODO LocalDate cell
            }
        }

        // TODO return something appropriate here
        return null ;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you James! I am still confused as to where it gets the type from? I would have expected something like `SimpleObjectProperty< Object >` which doesn't work. Why not?

Comment: I'll also note that, while the compiler asks for an instance of an 'ObservableValue<Object>' (an abstract class), the class is is inherited in 'SimpleObjectProperty' very-far down its inherited hierarchy.

Comment: `ObservableValue` is an interface, not a class. (So there isn't such a well-defined notion of the depth in the hierarchy anyway.)

Comment: James answered in the above post:  "The compiler just looks at the compile-time type of the value you are returning. The compile-time type of (String) item is String (basically by definition of what a downcast is). The compile-time type of (StringProperty) item is StringProperty. Note that StringProperty is a subtype of ObservableValue<String>, but not of ObservableValue<Object>. – James_D "